# Webpack 4 With Aurelia Not Automatically Doing Splitting

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia

For some reason after upgrading everything, I cannot get my webpack to split the code into chunks so my main js file is 5mb. Any ideas why this is not working?  Below is a screenshot showing what the output is.  The project is using aurelia, but I don't think that matter.  Why isn't this splitting into multiple bundles based on the routes?  This was working well in webpack 2 with the commonchunks plugin.

[image]

Here is my webpack config:

```
import { merge } from '@easy-webpack/core';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HappyPack = require('happypack');
const path = require("path");
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require("aurelia-webpack-plugin");
const webpackPort = parseInt(process.env.WEBPACK_PORT) || 9000;
const webpackHost = process.env.WEBPACK_HOST || 'localhost';
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() || (process.env.NODE_ENV = 'local');
const isHMR = process.argv.join('').indexOf('hot') > -1 || !!process.env.WEBPACK_HMR;
const title = 'My Title';
const baseUrl = '/';
const rootDir = __dirname;
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
                                          "filename" : '[name]-css.css'
                                         });
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
                                           "filename" : '[name]-less.css'
                                          });

let plugins = [
               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "css1",
                              "loaders" : ['css-loader']
                             }),
               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "css2",
                              "loaders" : ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                             }),

               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "less1",
                              "loaders" : ['css-loader', 'less-loader']
                             }),
               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "less2",
                              "loaders" : ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
                             }),
               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "ts",
                              "threads" : 2,
                              "loaders" : [{
                                            "path" : "ts-loader",
                                            "query" : {
                                                       happyPackMode: true
                                                      }
                                           }]
                             }),
               new HappyPack({
                              "id" : "js",
                              "loaders" : ['babel-loader']
                             }),
               new AureliaPlugin(),
               new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                                          $: "jquery",
                                          jQuery: "jquery",
                                          "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                                          'Promise': 'bluebird',
                                         }),
                new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
                new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
                                              "au-table": [ './au-table', './au-table-pagination', './au-table-pagination.html', './au-table-select', './au-table-sort' ],
                                              "aurelia-authentication": ["./authFilterValueConverter", "./authenticatedFilterValueConverter", "./authenticatedValueConverter" ],
                                              "aurelia-mdl-plugin" : ['./mdl'],
                                              "aurelia-froala-editor": [ './froala-editor' ],
                                            }),

                 //new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()
               ];

plugins.push(extractCSS);
plugins.push(extractLESS);

let base = {
            entry: { 
                    main: [
                           //'whatwg-fetch', 
                           'aurelia-bootstrapper',
                           ] 
                   },
            output: {
                     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist_"+process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase()),
                     publicPath: baseUrl,
                     filename: (ENV === 'prod' || ENV === 'stage' || ENV === 'qa' || ENV === 'dev') ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
                     sourceMapFilename: (ENV === 'prod' || ENV === 'stage' || ENV === 'qa' || ENV === 'dev') ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
                     chunkFilename: (ENV === 'prod' || ENV === 'stage' || ENV === 'qa' || ENV === 'dev') ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js',
                    },
            resolve: {
                      extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
                      modules: ["src", "node_modules", 'kendo/js'],
                      symlinks: false,
                     },
            module: {
                     rules: [
                             {
                              test: /\.css$/i,
                              issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
                              use: (ENV !== 'local') ? extractCSS.extract({
                                                                           fallback: 'style-loader',
                                                                           use: 'happypack/loader?id=css1',
                                                                          }) 
                                                     : 'happypack/loader?id=css2'
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.css$/i,
                              issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
                              // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
                              // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
                              use: 'happypack/loader?id=css1'
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.less$/i,
                              use: (ENV !== 'local') ? extractLESS.extract({
                                                                            fallback: 'style-loader',
                                                                            use: 'happypack/loader?id=less1',
                                                                           }) 
                                                     : 'happypack/loader?id=less2', 
                              issuer: {
                                       // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside templates
                                       test: /\.[tj]s$/i,
                                      }
                             },
                             { 
                              test: /\.ts$/i, 
                              use: 'happypack/loader?id=ts',
                              include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 
                              exclude: /node_modules/ 
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.js$/,
                              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|src)/,
                              use: 'happypack/loader?id=js',
                             },
                             { 
                              test: /\.html$/i, use: ["html-loader"] 
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.mp4$/,
                              loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=video/mp4'
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.ogv$/,
                              loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=video/ogv'
                             },
                             {
                              test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                              loader: 'expose-loader?Promise'
                             },
                             {
                              test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'
                             }
                            ]
                    },
            plugins: plugins
           }

const local = {
               mode: 'development',
               // output: {
               //          filename: 'bundle.js',
               //         },
               devServer: {
                           port: webpackPort,
                           host: '0.0.0.0',
                           historyApiFallback: true,
                           watchOptions: {
                                          aggregateTimeout: 300,
                                          poll: 1000
                                         },
                          },
              }

const production = {
                    mode: 'production',
                    devtool: '#source-map',
                    plugins: [
                              new WebpackMd5Hash(),
                              new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
                              // new (webpack as any).LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                              //                                           test: /\.html$/i,
                              //                                           minimize: true,
                              //                                           removeAttributeQuotes: false,
                              //                                           caseSensitive: true
                              //                                          })
                             ]
                   }

const variables = {
                   plugins: [
                             new CleanWebpackPlugin(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist_"+process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase()), {"verbose" : false}),
                             // literally replaces all mentions of a given variable in your code with the given value
                             new DefinePlugin({
                                               ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV),
                                               HMR: isHMR,
                                               'process.env': {
                                                               NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV),
                                                               HMR: isHMR,
                                                               WEBPACK_PORT: JSON.stringify(webpackPort),
                                                               WEBPACK_HOST: JSON.stringify(webpackHost),
                                                               VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_appversion),
                                                               BUILD: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_build),
                                                               BRANCH: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase())
                                                              }
                                             })
                            ]
                  }

const fontsAndImages = {
                        module: {
                                 rules: [
                                         // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files
                                         { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
                                         { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
                                         { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
                                         { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
                                        ]
                                }
                       }

const generateIndexHtml = {
                           plugins: [
                                     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                                                            template: 'index.ejs',
                                                            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
                                                            minify: ENV === 'prod' ? {
                                                                                      removeComments: true,
                                                                                      collapseWhitespace: true
                                                                                     } 
                                                                                   : undefined,
                                                                                     metadata: 
                                                                                     {
                                                                                      title, ENV, isHMR
                                                                                     }
                                                           })
                                    ]
                          }

const copyFiles = {
                   plugins: [
                             new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                                                    { from: 'favicon.png', to: 'favicon.png' },
                                                    { from: 'apple-touch-icon.png', to: 'apple-touch-icon.png' },
                                                    { from: 'manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json' },
                                                    { from: 'src/main.css', to: 'src/main.css' },
                                                    { from: 'images/**/*'},
                                                    { from: 'widget/**/*'},
                                                    { from: 'notifications-sw.js', to: 'notifications-sw.js' },
                                                   ])
                            ]
                  }

const config = merge(
                     base,
                     ENV === 'prod' || ENV === 'stage' || ENV === 'qa' || ENV === 'dev' ? production : local,
                     variables,
                     fontsAndImages,
                     generateIndexHtml,
                     ...(
                         ENV === 'prod' || ENV === 'stage' || ENV === 'qa' || ENV === 'dev' ? [copyFiles] : []
                        ),
                    )

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my app.ts:

```
import {AuthenticateStep} from 'aurelia-authentication';
import AppRoutes from './configs/routes';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {Router, RouterConfiguration, Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';
import {AppState} from './resources/global/appState';
import {NotificationsInit} from './libs/notificationsInit';

import './resources/global/less/base/base.less';
import './resources/global/less/layout/layout.less';

import '../kendo/styles/web/kendo.common.less';
import '../kendo/styles/web/kendo.common-material.less';
import '../kendo/styles/web/kendo.material.less';

import './components/nonAppHeader/nonAppHeader.less';

@inject(AppState, Router, EventAggregator)
export class App {
                  router: Router;
                  appState: any;
                  eventAggregator: any;

                  constructor(appState, router, eventAggregator)
                               {
                                this.router = router;
                                this.appState = appState;
                                this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator; 


                                if (this.appState.isLoggedIn)
                                 {
                                  new NotificationsInit(this.appState, this.eventAggregator);
                                 }
                               }

                  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) 
                                  {
                                   var step = {
                                     run: (navigationInstruction, next) => {

                                      if(this.appState.isLoggedIn === true)
                                       {
                                        if (this.appState.userInfo.status !== 9 && navigationInstruction.config.settings.admin === true)
                                         {
                                          return next.cancel(new Redirect('treks'));
                                         }
                                       }
                                      else if (navigationInstruction.config.settings.admin === true)
                                       {
                                        return next.cancel(new Redirect('/'));
                                       }

                                      return next();
                                     }
                                   };

                                   config.addPreRenderStep(step);
                                   config.title = 'My site';
                                   config.options.pushState = true;
                                   config.options.root = '/';
                                   config.addPipelineStep('postcomplete', PostCompleteStep);
                                   config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthenticateStep); // Add a route filter so only authenticated uses are authorized to access some routes

                                   config.map(AppRoutes["AppRoutes"]); 

                                   config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {

                                     window.dataLayer.push({
                                                            "event" : "404"
                                                           }); 

                                     return "application/404/404";
                                   });

                                   this.router = router;
                                  }
                  }

class PostCompleteStep {
                        run(routingContext, 
                            next) 
                            {
                             let metaInfoTmpl;

                             if (routingContext.config.moduleId !== "trek/trek/trek")
                              {
                                metaInfoTmpl = `<link rel="canonical" href="`+window.location.href+`" />
                                                <meta name="og:title" content="`+routingContext.config.title+` | Trekeffect">
                                                <meta name="og:site_name" content="`+routingContext.config.title+` | Trekeffect">
                                                <meta name="twitter:title" content="`+routingContext.config.title+` | Trekeffect">`;
                              }

                             if (routingContext.config.settings !== undefined)
                             {
                              if(routingContext.config.settings.metaDescription !== undefined)
                              {
                               metaInfoTmpl += `<meta name="description" content="`+routingContext.config.settings.metaDescription+`">
                                                 <meta name="og:description" content="`+routingContext.config.settings.metaDescription+`">
                                                 <meta name="twitter:description" content="`+routingContext.config.settings.metaDescription+`">`;
                              }

                              $('link[rel="canonical"], meta[name="og:title"], meta[name="og:site_name"], meta[name="twitter:title"], meta[name="description"], meta[name="og:description"], meta[name="twitter:description"]').remove();
                              $('head').append(metaInfoTmpl);
                             }

                             $(window).scrollTop(0);
                             $("body").removeClass().addClass(routingContext.config.name);

                             //Store the last visited url in local storage for Google Tag Manager
                             setTimeout(()=>{
                              localStorage.setItem("lastURL", window.location.pathname);
                             }, 2000);

                             //mt('send', 'pageview', {email: 'my@email.com', firstname: 'John'});

                             // window.dataLayer.push({
                             //  "event" : "aureliaPageView"
                             // });

                             //OfflinePluginRuntime.install();

                             return next();
                            } 
                       }
```

And here is my the class that contains a few of my routes:

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export default { 
                "AppRoutes" : [{
                                route: '',
                                name: 'homepage',
                                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('application/homepage/homepage'),
                                title: 'lorem',
                                appPage: false,
                                settings: {
                                           "metaDescription" : "lorem"
                                          }
                               },
                               {
                                route: 'about',
                                name: 'about',
                                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('application/about/about'),
                                title: 'About Us',
                                appPage: false,
                                settings: {
                                           "metaDescription" : "lorem."
                                          }
                               },
                               {
                                route: 'affiliates',
                                name: 'affiliates',
                                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('integrations/affiliates/affiliates'),
                                title: 'Affiliates',
                                appPage: false
                               },

                              ]
               }
```

EDIT: When I add in moduleName I get this loader error:
[image]

UPDATE: When platform moduleName has the same ID, in this case 'story/stories/stories', the first route gets corrupt and throws a can't find module error.  How can we fix this?

```
{
                 route: 'stories',
                 name: 'stories',
                 moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('story/stories/stories', "featureStories"),
                 title: 'Featured Stories',
                 appPage: true,
                },
                {
                 route: 'stories/published',
                 name: 'storiesPublished',
                 moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('story/stories/stories', "stories"),
                 title: 'Published Stories',
                 appPage: true,
                },
```

Comment: That's a huge webpack config but at first glance it looks OK. I'm assuming you split by passing appropriate parameters to `moduleName`... can you add your routing table as an example?

Comment: @jods I have added more information for you.  Any ideas?  And yes, my webpack is large but most of it really is needed. I trimmed a lot of it down.

Comment: @jods Any thoughts on my updated comment?  I'm still having an issue.

Comment: Not sure if this can work. You have the same module in two different chunks, is that intended? I think that WP can do that but the two modules would have different ids. Problem is that AureliaPlugin will preserve a single module name `story/stories/stories` for both. I have not debugged this but I guess that when it comes to loading `story/stories/stories` it gets confused where to find it. Wouldn't that be better if you didn't duplicate your module?

Comment: @jods I'm not duplicating the module.  For example, on that module I am passing in different parameters and loading different content based on that page.  Leveraging the same component makes sense.  This worked in the old version of the aurelia plugin by the way, but does not work in webpack 4.   I am forced to revert back to an old version of webpack in order to have good splitting.

Comment: @jods How else would I clearly define different routes for the same component without duplicating the modules?

Comment: You are putting the same module into 2 different chunks. Once in "featureStories" and second time in "stories". Try to use same chunk for both routes.

Comment: Which tool are you using to create the image like in your post? Does the size of blocks relate to the respective module size in the final bundle?

Answer (score 1):

> This was working well in webpack 2 with the commonchunks plugin.

From this remark I'm gonna assume you didn't split your routes inside your code but hard-coded some chunks repartition in your webpack 2 config instead.

Since that config is gone, there's no reason anything would be split anymore.

You should create split points when importing dependencies in your code by passing chunk names to `moduleName`.

For example:

```
{ route: 'admin', /* ... */, moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./Pages/admin', /* chunk: */ 'admin') }
```

Reference:
https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/Managing-dependencies#code-splitting

Comment: yeah that works!  I used to have this in my routes, but then removed them because when I add them back in I get a loader error! "bundle.js:186 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" Code splitting now works with the module name added but building locally causes that loader error. I have added the loader error above.

Comment: Can you open an issue with a small repro in Github? 
Looks like a bug and we won't be able to fix that over StackOverflow.

Comment: BTW that error comes from a LESS file?? That's _very_ strange, I don't see the relationship with the main code at all.

Comment: ok so that was crazy.  Turns out there is no bug and I had to just recompile that less file.  Somehow the loader had cached it or something.  Weird.

Comment: Glad everything turned out ok